# Equivalente FileInputStream en PHP

Tags: php, java, sql-server, pdf

Me gustaría pasar un fichero PDF a una cadena de texto binaria para almacenarlo en un campo de una base de datos SQL Server (VarBinary).

El codigo de Java que se encarga de almacenarlo es el siguiente:

```
FileInputStream   fis = new FileInputStream(doc);
stmt.setBinaryStream(7, fis, (int) image.length());
System.out.println((int) image.length());
stmt.execute();
```

¿Cual sería el equivalente en PHP? Estoy usando la funcion **file_get_contents()** pero no tiene nada que ver lo que obtengo en Java con esto.

Para visualizarlo desde PHP hago lo siguiente:

```
$content = sqlsrv_get_field( $result, 1,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));
file_put_contents($path, $content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo es correcto, [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) es el equivalente al código java que tienes. En java tienes que indicar de que byte a que byte leer el archivo, en PHP no es necesario. **file_get_contents()** te devuelve todo el binario del archivo a una variable como si fuera cadena de texto. Ahora lo que tienes que hacer para guardarlo es un insert como si guardaras una cadena de texto. La diferencia es que esa variable tienes que escaparla con [real_escape_string del objeto mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) o usar [sentencias preparadas si usas PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Ejemplo de mysqli:

```
$pdf=file_get_contents($path);
$pdfStr = $mysqli->real_escape_string($pdf);

if ($mysqli->query("INSERT into pdf (Name) VALUES ('$pdfStr')")) {
   printf("%d fila insertada.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
}
```

Tambien puedes revisar [como insertar y recuperar datos binarios usando PDO y PHP](https://maanasroyy.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/insert-retrive-binary-data-in-mysql-using-pdo-php/).
Si lo que quieres es leer byte a byte el archivo tienes que usar [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) y [fread](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

**Actualización:**
Perdón no me habia fijado que es para sql server y yo puse código para mysql. Pero si usas sqlsrv [aqui hay ejemplos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php). Aunque hacia sql server solo esta la opcion de sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Perfecto, me has resuelto el problema. Lo unico que solo he tenido que preparar la variable primero, ya que me daba error si no.
$contentstring = array ($content,null,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));